# Matching three underscore strings at the start of end of non-whitespace text chunks depending on immediate context

Tags: javascript, regex

In all cases listed below, I want to match only `___` (three underscores).

To make it clear, I am trying to match 3 underscores either not immediately preceded or not immediately followed with an underscore character and:

- if a character other than whitespace and `_` precedes the `___`, match last 3 (*test3_***___**)
- if a character other than whitespace and `_` follows the `___`, match first 3 (**___***____test5*).

See [my current attempt](https://regex101.com/r/2cHd9m/1):

```
((?<=_)___|___(?=_)|___)
```

Tested with:

```
test1___(test2 ___)
   test3____ ___
  ___test4 + ____test5
```

All cases are matching correctly except for "test3": it matches first 3 underscores instead of the last 3.

Comment: What is the rule here? To match `___` exactly, you need `(?<!_)___(?!_)`, however, it won't find a match in `____test5`. What is your intention?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In all cases I want to match only 3_ when there are 4_ for test3 rule is to match last 3_ when there are characters preceding the 4_

Comment: Maybe you want to match either 3 `_`s exactly, or any 3 `_`s that are located at the start of string or right after a whitespace? `(?<!_)___(?!_)|(?<!\S)___`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2cHd9m/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looked at it: not exactly, I want to ALWAYS match 3_ either at start or at end depending on context of characters preceding or following : if preceding, match last 3 if following match first 3. With your regex there's no match at all.

Comment: Ok, please clarify: 1) "*either at start or at end*" - start and end of *what*? 2) "*depending on context of characters*" - what (kind of) characters?

Comment: Try `(?<=[^\W_])___|___(?=[^\W_])|(?<!_)___(?!_)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2cHd9m/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew test3 OK but test5 KO: it doesn't match rule "match last 3 if following" ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 1) "either at start or at end" - start and end of _ symbols 2) "depending on context of characters (any character except blanks)"

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear. Please show what exactly you want to match in the above strings. And see https://regex101.com/r/2cHd9m/4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to match what in () : test3 - (+++) and (+++ ) -test5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<!_)___(?=_*[^\s_])|(?<=[^\s_]_*)___(?!_)|(?<!_)___(?!_)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2cHd9m/4). *Details*:

- `(?<!_)___(?=_*[^\s_])` - a `___` string not immediately preceded with a `_` char and that is immediately followed with any zero or more underscores and then any char other than whitespace and `_`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[^\s_]_*)___(?!_)` - a `___` string that is not immediately followed with another `_` char and immediately preceded with any char other than whitespace and `_` and then any zero or more underscores
- `|` - or
- `(?<!_)___(?!_)` - three underscores neither preceded nor followed with another `_` char.